# Why does this add 10 to all the elements in my List C#?

Tags: c#

Hi hello I'm new to C# and I was just wondering why this prints a 1 before all the elements in my list.
[image]

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> primes = new List<int> { 4, 5, 6 };
            for (int i = 0; i < primes.Count; i++)
            {
                int prime = primes[i];
                Console.WriteLine(prime + '\n');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You also may want to read about the differences between single quotes and double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Due to [binary numeric promotion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#binary-numeric-promotions) occurring with the use of the predefined [`+` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#addition-operator) in `prime + '\n'`, both operands will be converted to type `int`.  The second operand, `'\n'`, becomes `10` when converted to `int`.  Thus, your expression has the effect of adding `10` to each value of `prime`, just as if you had written...

```cs
Console.WriteLine(prime + 10);
```

Since you are using Visual Studio, there are a couple quick ways to observe what decisions the compiler is making.  The first is to hover the mouse over the `+` operator, which shows this [IntelliSense QuickInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/ide/using-intellisense#quick-info) popup...

[image: IntelliSense QuickInfo popup when hovering over the +(int, int) operator in Visual Studio 2019]

There you can see that `int` addition is being performed, which takes two `int`s and returns an `int`.  The other is to hover the mouse over `WriteLine`, which shows this QuickInfo popup...

[image: IntelliSense QuickInfo popup when hovering over the Console.WriteLine(int) method in Visual Studio 2019]
There you can see that it is choosing the overload of `Console.WriteLine()` that accepts a single `int` parameter because the result of `prime + '\n'` is an `int`.

Also note you don't need to append a `'\n'` when calling `WriteLine()` (emphasis on **`Line`**) because that is done for you.  Contrast this method with [`Console.Write()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.console.write).

Answer (score 1):

In `Console.WriteLine` method you have `prime + '\n'` expression. First operand in this expression, on the left side of operator `+`, is `prime` and it is of `int` type. Second operand `'\n'` is of type `char`.

`char` type and `int` type are classified in C# as **integral types**, which basically means that `char` is also an integer. There is implicit conversion from type `char` to type `int` which means that type `char` will be converted to type `int` if there is such possibility and need in the expression.

There are two questions:

- Why is type `char` implicitly converting to type `int` in `prime + '\n'` expression?
- Why is expression `prime + '\n'` adding value *10* to `prime`?

The answer to first question is that this overload of operator `+` takes two operands of type `int`. There is no overload of operator `+` that takes one operand of type `int` and the other of type `char`, in spite of the order of operands. Therefore operand of type `char` will be implicitly converted to type `int`. Even if you explicitly write that operand of type `int` should be treated as type `char` by writing `(char)prime` the result will be the same, because there is no the overload of operand `+` that takes two operands of type `char` and both operands will be implicitly converted to type `int`.

The answer to second question is that the integer value of character `'\n'` is *10*. You can read more about it in [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) article.

You can do two things:

1. Remove character `'\n'` from the `Console.WriteLine` because that method already sets new line at the end of line.
2. Use `Console.Write` and instead of character `'\n'` use string that contains only that character, `"\n"`, so the line would look like this: `Console.WriteLine(prime + "\n");`. This time will be used overloaded operator `+` that takes an operand of type `object` and an operand of type `string`. Operand of type `object`, in this case `prime`, will be implicitly converted to type `string` and those two strings will be concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

when calling `WriteLine()` you don't need to append `\n`
now the mistake is that you print `\n` as character (single quotes) and not string (double quotes) which is converted to `int` [and has the value of 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/csharpfaq/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available)

you can try it

```
Console.WriteLine((int)'\n');
```